# How to get the snooze time for a scheduled reminder?

Tags: windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks

I have been having some trouble with reminders as of lately. I was wondering how the snooze feature works? When snooze is pressed on a reminder, is a new reminder created or is the same reminder scheduled for later?

The reason i ask is that i want to update a textblock in my app that shows the time of the reminder. My first thought was to look upp the reminder that has been snoozed and check the BeginTime property of the returned ScheduledAction. But this property had not been changed since the reminder was first created.

So, simply put, how do i get the scheduled time for a ScheduledAction including one or more possible snoozes ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this information.
All you can do is trigger the notification and then it's up to the user to respond to the notification as they feel is appropriate.

That doesn't mean you can't include additional reminder information within your app, if appropriate.